# Is there a way to remove undefined fields from an elasticsearch-dsl Document before saving?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

Assume I have a `Document` defined as `MyDoc`. I want to save the data in `doc` to my index, but I don't want any undefined fields, in this case `unknown`, making it to my index. Does `elasticsearch-dsl` have a way of handling this or is there a known workaround?

```
class MyDoc(Document):
    name = Text()
    age = Integer()
    course = Keyword()

    class Index:
        name = "test-index"


doc = {"name": "John Doe", "age": "3", "unknown": "yes"}

my_doc = MyDoc(**doc)
```

Comment: Defining your mapping as being [`strict`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic.html#dynamic-parameters) would prevent unwanted data to be stored in your Elasticsearch server.

Comment: @Val Thank you. To avoid errors whenever the mapping is broken, I ended writing a custom method to do the cleaning on the `Document` before saving

Comment: Glad to know you figure something out